When People ask me What is Buddhism Can anyone give me a short, simple answer to explain please
So I am into buddha learning for some years now, and some people ask me
" What is Buddhism" , with a blank look on their face.
Based on their level of experience, which is pretty much zero yet with genuine wonderment, I have tailored my answer to what I consider the best at that time.
I have, over the years, delivered the following answers:
"Buddhism is about raising your level of awareness."
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to say or explain
also,
" Learning about the Buddha is about studying sutra, or the sacred texts, and then doing your best to live the sutras."
and this one too,
" The Buddha taught that he got there and being a human being, as you are a human being, you can also follow this path should you choose. "
I am seeking further answers to this genuine question honest people ask me.

This question seems to be a duplicate of other past questions. Do the linked questions answer your question?
